# Как сделать перед циклом проверку?

Tags: javascript

Нужна ваша помощь.
Есть задачка, которую, я никак не могу толком понять. Помогите понять, что и как.
Не могу понять суть, ковыряю, читаю, но что-то не догоняю...

**УСЛОВИЕ ЗАДАЧИ.**

> Есть input i-91 и i-92 куда пользователь может ввести числа. По нажатию кнопки b-9 должна запускаться функция f9, которая выводит в out-9 числа от меньшего введенного до большего включительно, с шагом 1. Разделитель пробел. Если пользователь ввел 4 и 8 и нажал кнопку, мы получим:
>
> 4 5 6 7 8 если ввел 8 и 6, то получим 6 7 8 Задача решается с помощью
>   цикла. Подсказка - вначале делаем проверку, а потом запускаем цикл.

```js
function t9() {

  let in91 = document.querySelector('.i-91').value;
  let in92 = document.querySelector('.i-92').value;

  let out9 = '';

  for (let i = in91; i < in92; i++ ) {
    out9 += i + ' ';
  }

  document.querySelector('.out-9').innerHTML = out9;
}

document.querySelector('.b-9').onclick = t9;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-control">Input i-91 <input type="number" class="i-91"></div>
<div class="form-control">Input i-92 <input type="number" class="i-92"></div>
<button class="button-primary b-9">Task-9</button>
<div class="out-9"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function t9() {

  let in91 = +document.querySelector('.i-91').value;
  let in92 = +document.querySelector('.i-92').value;

  let start = Math.min(in91, in92);
  let end = Math.max(in91, in92);

  let out9 = '';

  for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    out9 += i + ' ';
  }

  document.querySelector('.out-9').innerHTML = out9;
}

document.querySelector('.b-9').onclick = t9;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-control">Input i-91 <input type="number" class="i-91" value="4"></div>
<div class="form-control">Input i-92 <input type="number" class="i-92" value="8"></div>
<button class="button-primary b-9">Task-9</button>
<div class="out-9"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Подскажите, а есть еще варианты перед циклом проверить?

Comment: @Дмитрий "есть еще варианты перед циклом проверить" - что это значит?

Comment: Я имел ввиду, есть литеще варианты

Comment: @Дмитрий Варианты чего? Хотите - напишите, используя `if`.

Comment: Спасибо! Уже разобрался.

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно, что раз вам надо вывести от меньшего числа к большему, то вам надо найти меньшее и большее. Можно сделать проверку, если `in91` больше `in92`, то поменять их местами.
Еще у вас в цикле условие не соответствует задаче. Будьте внимательнее.

```js
function t9() {
  let in91 = +document.querySelector('.i-91').value;
  let in92 = +document.querySelector('.i-92').value;
  
  if (in91 > in92) {
    [in91, in92] = [in92, in91];
  }

  let out9 = '';
  for (let i = in91; i <= in92; i++ ) {
    out9 += i + ' ';
  }

  document.querySelector('.out-9').innerHTML = out9;
}

document.querySelector('.b-9').onclick = t9;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-control">Input i-91 <input type="number" class="i-91"></div>
<div class="form-control">Input i-92 <input type="number" class="i-92"></div>
<button class="button-primary b-9">Task-9</button>
<div class="out-9"></div>
```